# CAC Card Digital signatures in LibreOffice

Tags: signature

All,

I've been wondering if there is an approveit equivalent for Libre Office that supports the applying of digital certificate signatures from my CAC card to say, writer or impress, or calc the way I can with MS programs.

Any help would be appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice supports use of Digital Signature. There's a step by step guide on how to do that [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Applying_Digital_Signatures). Take a look.

Comment: Okay so I followed the step by step, and Libre recognizes there being a signature in the document, but there isn't any visible signature block like in MS... which unfortunately, is required for who I am submitting the document to. Is there any way to make the signature block visible in the text of the document?